Redshift sortkey and distkey design when there are multiple columns used for querying data
My question is let's suppose I have a table A with 216 columns  :
CREATE TABLE test_data
(
    fund_name     varchar(255)
    fund_desc     varchar(255)
    accountId     varchar(255)   
    postdate      date,
    effectiveDate date,
    businessdate  Date,
    activeTill    TimeStamp
) 

Our use case is as follows:

Frequent  updates to the table as data  is getting loaded based on kafka events through out the day.

Historical Data stores .Hence billions of rows and data keep getting added every day.

10 node cluster.


We have below filter criteria for our data distribution:
activeTill will always have value as "9999-09-99,23:09:0' for all active record; accountId count can max go up to 12k distinct values.
Query #1:
select * 
from fund_data 
where postdate between '2024-06-01' and '2024-06-20' 
  and accountId in ('1234', '56789', '0009') 
  and activeTill > sysdate

Query #2:
select * 
from fund_data 
where effectiveDate between '2024-06-01' and '2024-06-20' 
  and accountId in ('1234', '56789', '0009') 
  and activeTill > sysdate

Query #3:
select * 
from fund_data 
where businessdate between '2024-06-01' and '2024-06-20' 
  and accountId in ('1234', '56789', '0009') 
  and activeTill > sysdate


In our current set up, distkey is AUTO and SORT_KEY as (postdate, accountId, sysdate).

The query performance was ok  when only postDate was getting used in where clause as it is the 1st sort key.

Now since consumers started using other date fields equally, those queries performing worst.

So, looking for recommendation ,in such cases what can be ideal SORT key and DIST key.



I have a table A with 216 columns - but your table structure shown only has 7 columns - did you mean you have 216 rows of data in your table ?

This is a common optimization change that people have to go through.  How to balance the optimization gains for multiple sort keys.  I did a re:Invent talk that included this a few years back which may add some more context - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxfnWTiY7EM&t
This all comes down to optimizing the use of your block metadata.  In your example when you sort by postdate first this will use all the resolution of this column before any other column's data is used to order rows.  This means that values for postdate are lumped together resulting in metadata values for this column that have small ranges of values and therefore only a few blocks of data need to be read when querying based on this column in the WHERE clause.
However, the values for the other date columns, effectiveDate and businessdate, are going to be scattered all over the table.  So when these columns are in the WHERE clause the entire table's data needs to be read from disk.  This is likely what is causing a significant portion of the slowdown you are experiencing for these queries.  Check the scan steps for all 3 types of queries and note the number of rows of data read from disk for each.  This will likely confirm this theory.
So how do you "balance" the value of metadata for all 3 date columns?  You need to add columns that reduce the resolution for the first 2 sort keys. These "synthetic" columns don't replace the date columns used in queries but are only used for sorting the table.  (watch the video if this isn't clear) Also it is usually a good idea to identify these synthetic columns by giving them some identification in the name - like starting these with double underscore.
I propose you add 2 columns to your table - __postdate_sortkey and __effectiveDate_sortkey and use these as the first and second sortkeys of the table.  The third sortkey should be businessdate so that those queries will receive benefit too.  A good starting point for the definition of __postdate_sortkey could be date_trunc('year', postdate) and for __effectiveDate_sortkey, date_trunc('month', effectiveDate). Of course you will need to profile your performance to make sure this amount of coarseness is correct and this will need to be done when the table is vacuumed (resorted) and analyzed (metadata updated).
Again you don't change the query WHERE clauses.  This is just setting a new sort order for the table where the metadata for the actual date columns provides the needed optimization for all queries.  Note that this "balancing" of query performance will likely impact postdate queries slightly but that the overall solution performance will be greatly improved.
There are ways to inspect the metadata directly to better fine tune things but that is likely too involved for a quick answer here.  Hopefully this level of optimization isn't needed.
Hope this helps.

I'm curious why you wouldn't just use an interleaved sort key?

A few reasons.  Since these are dates their extent of values keeps increasing and this requires continual reworking of the interleaved key structure and resorting of the table.  Using compound keys can be set up to put new values 'at the end of the table'.  Interleaved keys doesn't change the granularity of the data and this keeps the lower keys (per interleaved region) from having much power.  Less granular data allows lower keys to improve block metadata.  Lastly, it is nearly impossible to debug/decode interleaved key impact on metadata to fine how to further improve performance.

Hi @BillWeiner, Got to know today there is another date field got added for query criteria: Settledate   So, another question ,if I put the  SORT KEY as (postdate ,effectiveDate ,Settledate .businessdate,accountid)  will the performance will be bad .Basically put all  date columns in sort key field.

To be clear we are talking about the ability of Redshift to scan a minimal amount of table data from disk using the block metadata.  This is one, quite often large, component of a query's performance.  In my experience it is challenging to get more than 3 uncorrelated columns to be effective at reducing table scans.  That said it is often the case that date columns are correlated and their data tends to track each other.  Do any of these dates track each other?  Do any pairs tend to occur in the same month?  These correlations will reduce the need for both of the correlated columns being used.

It is also important that the resolution of the earlier sort key columns is low (coarse).  Without allowing the later keys to do "work" this first key will have all the power and not improve the metadata for these other WHERE clauses. The amount of coarseness is dependent on a lot of factors.  This is where profiling your various queries and/or analyzing the block metadata comes in.

@BillWeiner another question, then If I put the accountId as the 1st key which is a string value though and max number of account_id  in our system that can go upto is  3000  and it is having the low (coarse).Putting String as 1st Sort key will it impact Redshift while meta data data block filtering.

Yes but will help with queries that have a WHERE clause with a narrow range of account_id's.  This may or may not be important to you.  Remember how the block metadata is structured.  Each 1MB block of each column has a metadata record that stores the max and min value for that block.  Every time Redshift scans a table it first compares these block extents to any WHERE clause values for that column.  If the block doesn't contain the needed value(s) it won't be read from disk (scanned).  Redshift also will not load any other column blocks for rows that aren't in the matching blocks.

What matters is the order that the rows are sorted in and this is based on the sort keys.  Every column has metadata that can be used to exclude blocks from scan.  Having a column in the sortkey list doesn't change this ability.  What matters is the max and min ranges for the blocks used in a WHERE clause.  Fewer blocks that match the WHERE clause means less data read from disk resulting in a fast scan phase of the query.  It's all about the sort order that makes the largest number of your WHERE clauses powerful.

Since you have only a few values of account_id this will have a minimal effect on the sorting power of the other keys.  Is this also your DISTKEY? This may or may not create issues.  However, you also need to think about INSERTing new data and VACUUMing.  It is likely that you have new data coming into the table with later date values.  Ideally you would want this data to be located when sorted at the "end" of the table to reduce UPSERT and VACUUM times.  This won't happen if you have account_id as your first sortkey.

Currently we  have dist key as AUTO .Due to huge size redshift has made it as EVEN.But we are thinking to move it as Dist key..In all our queries account_id will be passed..that  is must field.. along with account_id, queries will be fired with diff date parameters that i mentioned

Yes, do.  DISTKEY EVEN is another way of saying DISTKEY "RANDOM".  The value of DISTKEY EVEN is to prevent a novice user from setting up a situation where the data is highly skewed (on disk or during important queries).  It protects the user from themselves but adds no performance value.  Selecting the best distribution key is a whole other thread that again comes down to knowing your query patterns and your data.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
